# Assistance in building array of Exchange powershell output

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables, exchange-server-2016

I am trying to build a script that can get a list of members of a distribution group recursively, and then output the data in a way that is manipulable.

The below code works fine so far, but only outputs a final list of recipients on the screen, with two columns (Name, RecipientType). I have tried a couple of ways to instead output the results to a variable or array in order to manipulate it, however none of them have worked.

What would be the best way to take the `$Member` variable, and add it to another variable or array?

```
function Get-DistributionGroupMemberRecursive ($Identity) { 
    $GroupMembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $Identity
    foreach ($Member in $GroupMembers) { 
        if($Member.RecipientType -like "*Group") { 
            Get-DistributionGroupMemberRecursive -Identity $Member.Identity 
        }
        else {
            $Member
        }
    }
}

Get-DistributionGroupMemberRecursive -Identity some_address@domain
```

Comment: Looks to me that the function is actually outputting a collection (array) of `$Member` objects you can capture in a variable like this `$result = Get-DistributionGroupMemberRecursive -Identity some_address@domain`. Now you are just letting PowerShell output the `$Member` objects to the console window.

Comment: That's great, I didn't think of setting that as a variable, as I assume it was only outputting to the screen and not actually storing the output. I set it as a variable, and can now manipulate as I need! Thank you